# How do I configure my helm chart to pickup a rabbitmq community plugin?

Tags: rabbitmq, kubernetes-helm

GOAL:  To use a rabbitmq community plugin from https://www.rabbitmq.com/community-plugins.html in my **rabbitmq-ha** helm chart.

*Any plugins that do not ship with the server will need to be installed. Plugins are distributed as .ez archives (which are zip files with metadata). The files must be copied to one of the plugins directories specified by **$RABBITMQ_PLUGINS_DIR***.

PROBLEM:  How does the rabbitmq community plugin's .ev file get injected into the chart for use?

---

BACKGROUND:

For my example I am trying to install the latest version of the community plugin **rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange** into the latest stable version of **rabbitmq-ha**.

The name of the plugin is identified by adding this to my **values.yaml**:

```
amqp-rabbitmq:
  extraPlugins: |
    rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange,
```

And when I

```
helm install example .  --debug
```

it generates

```
# Source: example/charts/amqp-rabbitmq/templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: example-amqp-rabbitmq
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: amqp-rabbitmq
    chart: amqp-rabbitmq-1.38.2
    release: example
    heritage: Helm
data:
  enabled_plugins: |
    [
      rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange,
      rabbitmq_consistent_hash_exchange,
      rabbitmq_management,
      rabbitmq_peer_discovery_k8s
    ].

  rabbitmq.conf: |
    ## RabbitMQ configuration
    ## Ref: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/master/docs/rabbitmq.conf.example

    ## Authentification

    ## Clustering
    cluster_formation.peer_discovery_backend  = rabbit_peer_discovery_k8s
    cluster_formation.k8s.host = kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
    cluster_formation.k8s.address_type = hostname
    cluster_formation.node_cleanup.interval = 10
    # Set to false if automatic cleanup of absent nodes is desired.
    # This can be dangerous, see http://www.rabbitmq.com/cluster-formation.html#node-health-checks-and-cleanup.
    cluster_formation.node_cleanup.only_log_warning = true
    cluster_partition_handling = autoheal
    ## The default "guest" user is only permitted to access the server
    ## via a loopback interface (e.g. localhost)
    loopback_users.guest = false

    management.load_definitions = /etc/definitions/definitions.json

    ## Memory-based Flow Control threshold
    vm_memory_high_watermark.absolute = 256MB

    ## Auth HTTP Backend Plugin

    ## LDAP Plugin

    ## MQTT Plugin

    ## Web MQTT Plugin

    ## STOMP Plugin

    ## Web STOMP Plugin

    ## Prometheus Plugin

    ## AMQPS support
```

and creates 3 **k8s_amqp-rabbitmq_example-amqp-rabbitmq-*n*_default_...** containers.

The log in each container shows

```
2020-01-11 01:21:16.826 [info] <0.8.0> Server startup complete; 6 plugins started.

* rabbitmq_management

* rabbitmq_web_dispatch

* rabbitmq_consistent_hash_exchange

* rabbitmq_peer_discovery_k8s

* rabbitmq_management_agent

* rabbitmq_peer_discovery_common

2020-01-11 01:23:06.954 [info] <0.529.0> node 'rabbit@example-amqp-rabbitmq-1.example-amqp-rabbitmq-discovery.default.svc.cluster.local' up

2020-01-11 01:23:12.776 [info] <0.529.0> rabbit on node 'rabbit@example-amqp-rabbitmq-1.example-amqp-rabbitmq-discovery.default.svc.cluster.local' up
```

I can successfully log into rabbitmq, create exchanges, queues, etc.

However, the desired **rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange** plugin is no where to be found.

- It is not mentioned in the log file anywhere.
- It does not show up in the **rabbit@example-amqp-rabbitmq-*n*.example-amqp-rabbitmq-discovery.default.svc.cluster.local-plugins-expand** folder with the other plugins.

When my application tries to use the helm installed rabbitmq-ha to create the delayed exchange it gets:

`'Error: Connection closed: 503 (COMMAND-INVALID) with message "COMMAND_INVALID - unknown exchange type 'x-delayed-message'"`

It works with the non kubernetes instances of rabbitmq where I could easily install the plugin.

---

I have spent several days searching the web for a clear example, hints, and clues as to how to avail the rabbitmq-ha chart of a community plugin and not progressed.

Any ideas out there?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

Building a custom chart is no longer nececarry i did it with this values.yaml

```
## Plugins to enable
##
plugins: 'rabbitmq_management rabbitmq_peer_discovery_k8s'

## Community plugins to download during container initialization.
## Combine it with extraPlugins to also enable them.
##
communityPlugins: |
  https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange/releases/download/3.8.9/rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange-3.8.9-0199d11c.ez

## Extra plugins to enable
## Use this instead of `plugins` to add new pluginsmv ra  
##
extraPlugins: |
  rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap 
  rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange
```

Comment: worked for me when I placed them in 1 line separated by a space, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example to install and enable two [RabbitMQ community plugins](https://www.rabbitmq.com/community-plugins.html):

- rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange
- rabbitmq_message_timestamp

#### Step 1: Get the Helm chart:

```
$ helm search repo rabbitmq
NAME               CHART VERSION    APP VERSION DESCRIPTION                                       
bitnami/rabbitmq   6.25.4           3.8.3       Open source message broker software that implem...

$ helm pull --untar bitnami/rabbitmq
```

#### Step 2: Update file `statefulset.yaml`

```
...
# Install community plugins
pushd /opt/bitnami/rabbitmq/plugins/
curl -LO https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange/releases/download/v3.8.0/rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange-3.8.0.ez
curl -LO https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-message-timestamp/releases/download/v3.8.0/rabbitmq_message_timestamp-3.8.0.ez
popd
# End of installing community plugins
exec rabbitmq-server
...
```

[image]

#### Step 3: Install RabbitMQ with the two plugins enabled

```
$ cd rabbitmq
$ helm install rmq . --set rabbitmq.extraPlugins="rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange rabbitmq_message_timestamp"
```

#### Now you can verify that the two plugins have been installed

```
$ kubectl get pod
NAME             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
rmq-rabbitmq-0   1/1     Running   0          3m32s

$ kubectl exec -it rmq-rabbitmq-0 bash
I have no name!@rmq-rabbitmq-0:/$ rabbitmq-plugins list
Listing plugins with pattern ".*" ...
 Configured: E = explicitly enabled; e = implicitly enabled
 | Status: * = running on rabbit@rmq-rabbitmq-0.rmq-rabbitmq-headless.default.svc.cluster.local
 |/
[  ] rabbitmq_amqp1_0                  3.8.3
[  ] rabbitmq_auth_backend_cache       3.8.3
[  ] rabbitmq_auth_backend_http        3.8.3
[  ] rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap        3.8.3
[  ] rabbitmq_auth_backend_oauth2      3.8.3
[  ] rabbitmq_auth_mechanism_ssl       3.8.3
[  ] rabbitmq_consistent_hash_exchange 3.8.3
[E*] rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange 3.8.0
[  ] rabbitmq_event_exchange           3.8.3
[  ] rabbitmq_federation               3.8.3
[  ] rabbitmq_federation_management    3.8.3
[  ] rabbitmq_jms_topic_exchange       3.8.3
[E*] rabbitmq_management               3.8.3
[e*] rabbitmq_management_agent         3.8.3
[E*] rabbitmq_message_timestamp        3.8.0
[  ] rabbitmq_mqtt                     3.8.3
...
```

**Note**: My Helm version is `v3.1.1`

```
$ helm version
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.1.1", GitCommit:"afe70585407b420d0097d07b21c47dc511525ac8", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.13.8"}
```

Comment: tried this it worked for me like a charm! thank you

Comment: @Yuci apologies but where in statefulset.yaml does this patch go? I've downloaded the latest bitnami chart and statefulset.yaml exists in the templates folder but there is nothing in there that matches your text (e.g. rabbitmq-server) to tell me where this additional content goes in the yaml

Comment: @GrahamB At the time of answering the question, the Bitnami RabbitMQ chart version was 6.25.4, and now it is version 8.6.0 :-) To be clearer, I just updated the answer with a screenshot, so you would know exactly where in `statefulset.yaml` to install RabbitMQ community plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I think `rabbitmq-ha` default helm chart use the official rabbitMQ image, so it only contains [core plugins](https://www.rabbitmq.com/plugins.html#tier1-plugins).

I check the [chart config](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/rabbitmq-ha), it just set the `/etc/rabbitmq/enabled_plugins` conf file, plugin file will not be downloaded automatically.

There are two solutions:

- Build your custom rabbitmq image, ship the `rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange` file with it.
- Download the plugin file in initContainer, add it to your chart values `extraInitContainers`

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation regarding the core plugins.

Comment: I'd prefer not create a customized image just to add a community plugin.

I am able to use an initContainer to download the plugin to a volumeMount and to make the rabbitmq-ha pods aware of that volumeMount.

However, I have not figured out a way to make rabbitmq aware of the plugin.  

Documentation indicates that the path could be appended to an environment variable $RABBITMQ_PLUGINS_DIR but when I check the container's env, that variable is not defined.

And as far as I can figure out there is no way to copy the plugin directly to the /opt/rabbitmq/plugins directory.

Comment: @peasant All the rabbitmq configure and plugin files has the "101:100" owner permission. If you want to bind volumeMount file to the "/opt/rabbitmq/plugins" dir, the rabbitmq server process can not access the plugin file because of the owner permission restriction.

Comment: @peasant So I prefer to create a customized image.